# Ip адрес клиента php

Tags: php

Пытаюсь получить ip клиента через $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], с компьютера всё показывает, но с телефона выдаёт не ip, a "5a13:1gy3:670c:4fg1:0:7h:4574:f001".

В чем может быть проблема и как получить ip клиента?

Comment: а это и есть ip. Просто это ipv6,  а не ipv4.

Answer (score 0):

Телефон подключился с помощью [IPv6](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6).
Это и есть, то что вам нужно.

Современная инфраструктура и приложения стараются поддерживать этот протокол, и вам тоже стоит учитывать в своем коде новые IP адреса.

Comment: Ваш ответ больше на комментарий тянет.

Comment: @ΝNL993 может быть напишете свой ответ? Критикуешь - предлагай.

Comment: я вот свой комментарий раньше написал:) Но с предыдущим оратором полностью согласен.

Comment: @Максим не думаю что могу предложить вариант лучше.

Comment: Тут интересно то, что автор вопроса не видел ipv6. Но тут всякое бывает. тут не все знают, как могут ipv4 адреса выглядеть и не признать валидный адрес.

Comment: Увы, но не сталкивался с ipv6, так как до этого писал на c# и не работал с сетью.

Comment: А не подскажите можно ли его в ipv4 передавалать? Просто у меня уже написана функция для получения страны по ipv4, но увы не могу подружить её с ipv6

Comment: его не нужно переделывать в ipv4. Да и невозможно это так. А функцию получения страны по айпи нужно просто расширять.